# Missing workaround in SPFx JQuery WebPart

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, spfx-webparts

In the SPFx JQuery tutorial there is this instruction :-

For drop 1, there is a workaround needed when loading css files (later on in this tutorial we will show you how). For now, you need to include one other typing
`tsd install combokeys --save`

When I have finished adding all of the code in the instructions there is no other references to this workaround and I get a failure :-

> import styles from './JQuery.module.scss'; - cannot find module
>   ./JQuery.module.scss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you do your first successful build, that error in the IDE should go away.
See this issue in github - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/22

Comment: @Nigel, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: @SPDoctor - done